# Not able to to convert R data frame to Spark DataFrame

Tags: r, sparkr

When I try to convert my local dataframe in R to Spark DataFrame using:

```
raw.data <- as.DataFrame(sc,raw.data)
```

I get this error:

> 17/01/24 08:02:04 WARN RBackendHandler: cannot find matching method class org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils.getJavaSparkContext. Candidates are:
>   17/01/24 08:02:04 WARN RBackendHandler: getJavaSparkContext(class org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext)
>   17/01/24 08:02:04 ERROR RBackendHandler: getJavaSparkContext on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
>   Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :

The question is similar to 
[sparkR on AWS: Unable to load native-hadoop library and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650311/sparkr-on-aws-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-and)

Comment: Is this the only data.frame you are unable to coerce to Spark's DataFrame? Are there any special columns Spark may not be able to handle?

Comment: Try with `enableHiveSupport = FALSE` as option in SparkR session as shown in the answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik No I tried with IRIS dataset too... I am not able to create any Spark Dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't need to use `sc` if you are using the latest version of Spark. **I am using SparkR package having version 2.0.0 in RStudio**. Please go through following code (that is used to connect R session with SparkR session):

```
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "path-to-spark home/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
 }
 library(SparkR)
 library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R","lib")))
 sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "spark://master url:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))
```

Following is the output of R console:

```
> data<-as.data.frame(iris)
> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
> data.df<-as.DataFrame(data)
> class(data.df)
[1] "SparkDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"
```

Comment: I am using Spark version 1.6.2. sparkR.session is not supported in it.

Answer (score 0):

use this example code :

```
library(SparkR)
library(readr)

sc <- sparkR.init(appName = "data")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

old_df<-read_csv("/home/mx/data.csv")
old_df<-data.frame(old_df)
new_df <- createDataFrame( sqlContext, old_df)
```